# How to set icon transparent in imageview android

Tags: android, image, imageview, transparent

I have gridview custom android which display thumbnails of my product, I want to add transparent small magnifier on center imageview, so user know if they click thumbnails, they can get detail. How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Where is your code ? Show your custom gridview layout file.

Comment: my layout custom let see http://pastebin.com/T03XixuK

Comment: my gridview layout, see http://pastebin.com/Nj1Fiug2

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `FrameLayout` and add the transparent image in it as below:

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@layout/borderblack"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/tranparent"
         />
   <FrameLayout/>
```